# Bind attr handlebars helper ember.js with a specific value check

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

So I basically need to select a specific value from the selectbox.

So I am wondering how I can make `{{bind-attr}}` behave like this:

```
        <select id="research_status" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="finalized" {{bind-attr selected a_variable="finalized"}}>Finalized</option>
            <option value="in progress" {{bind-attr selected a_variable="in progress"}}>In progress</option>
        </select>
```

I couldn't find this in the documentation (I haven't looked into it too much though). But if there is another way of doing this that's a little simpler or maybe easier to work with please let me know.

I do not want to endup doing something like this

```
        <select id="research_status" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="finalized" {{bind-attr selected=isFinalized}}>Finalized</option>
            <option value="in progress" {{bind-attr selected=isInProgress}}>In progress</option>
        </select>
```

I know we can do it like this, but I do not want to go around creating unncessary variables.

I am retrieving this from a model so it'd be great to just check the value of that model's field and select that specific one in the select box (as shown in my first snippet of code).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I forgot how Handlebars helpers handle attributes. So my previous answer wouldn't work. But the `bind-attr` helper doesn't provide that kind of functionality, and is probably different enough where it can't be easily modified to do so. I believe your best bet would be to re-create the `bind-attr` helper, only using your custom syntax. You can find that code [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/binding.js#L724).

Again, I think you'd be better off just declaring a controller property. It only takes one line per property:

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    isFinalized: Ember.computed.equal('model.state', 'finalized'),
    isInProgress: Ember.computed.equal('model.state', 'in progress')
});
```

Comment: This is from the docs:
If you use {{bind-attr}} with a Boolean value, it will add or remove the specified attribute. For example, given this template.

How can I do it without a boolean value but still be able to do what I showed above.

I understand your answer, however.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. My code will add or remove the attribute as well. And I didn't user a boolean value, I used a variable and string literal.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer, I was wondering if this could be done using the {{bind-attr}} helper.

Comment: Actually, I noticed that there is something wrong with my answer. It won't work as you need it. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I am very new to ember, could you give me an example of how you'd do the controller property?

Comment: issue is I don't want to make a property for every select value. That seems very inefficient.

Comment: There's likely another way to accomplish the task you want. But it's hard to say without seeing your options and what they're used for. Can you update your post with more information?

Comment: In my model there is just a `state` key that can have two values `finalized` or `in progress`. They are just being displayed here, and updated if someone picks something else in the select.

Comment: If you only have two values, and they're static, I don't see why you can't just declare the properties. Use a Mixin or Component if you need that functionality elsewhere.

Comment: Because there are other parts of the app that will be similar however they will have more properties. It's annoying to keep creating this and does not seem intuitive at all.